# Re-Use a single view for different models in qml

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qml

This question is about QtQuick QML

[image: Each manin menu button will give sub menu options]

As you can see from picture. I have a main Menu and each main menu when clicked shows different sub menus with a text inside the box.

I'm using Model and View for displaying information.

So i have the `text data as a model`, and `View is ListView`

I know about using a single model and reusing for different views.

But how to do the way around. I have many data but my view is similar for all MainMenu items i click.

Is there any options like switch statement where I store all data in a single place and load each model for different MainMenu item Clicked

Thank you all!!

Comment: Why don't you use same delegate for all listviews that have similar view?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#details Qabstractproxymodel will help you i guess

Comment: Make multiple models and assign the one you want to the view when clicking.

Comment: @Velkan In that case if I have like 20 main menu options, then it becomes difficult to make so many models separately. I:m looking for like, save all data in a file or something, and create a controller to load them in a single view every time user clicks.

Comment: I don't see a problem here, just switch the model of the view...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of options

1. Use a single model and change its contents based on which sub menu it should be showing.
2. Use a list of models and let the main menu set the "current index" of that list.
3. Use a list of models internally in an interface object and set a "current sub menu model" property to the correct one on request
4. Use a single model that contains all sub menu items and a filter proxy model on top of it that reduces the list to the items for the currentöly active sub menu

Comment: I think 2nd and 3rd might be practical. let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: If you also want to change other properties, the use of states might be appropriate, mixed with any of the solutions proposed above. With this you also might add neat transitions for each change.